# Order of integration - double integration

Tags: integration

I have a change order of integration problem.  Ive sketched the graph and I think that I'm okay, just need to confirm in the integration signage. I dont know how to do the integration signs here.

Before integration $ 0 \le x \le \frac { -(y-5)}{3}$   and 0<= y <= 5  xy^2 dx dy

Reversal            $0 \le y \le 5-3x$   and    0<= x <=5  xy^2 dy dx

I happy to do the integration part.  Cheers

Comment: In your reversal $0\leq x\leq\frac53$ and
$$\int_0^\frac53\int_0^{5-3x}xy^2 dy dx=\int_0^\frac53x\dfrac{y^3}{3}\Big|_0^{5-3x}dx$$

Comment: Just a question, why 5/3?

Comment: The line $x=-\dfrac{y-5}{3}$ intersects $x$-axis in that point.

Comment: Many thanks, that makes perfect sense.